# How to unzip a gz file in SQL

Tags: sql-server, unzip

I have an DB.mdf and DB.ldf files used for a certain test.
During the test I recreate a database with them:

```
CREATE DATABASE restoredDB
    ON (FILENAME = 'C:\DB.mdf')
    LOG ON (FILENAME = 'C:\DB.ldf')  
    FOR ATTACH;
```

GO

Everything is working great so far. now, the DB.mdf and DB.ldf are way to big for the test folder, I need to compress them so that they will decompress only during a test, how do I do that?
I thought of compressing it into a gz file and decompress using xp_cmdshell, but I can't use xp_cmdshell due to security configuration...

Would appreciate any suggestions.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You cannot play with real DB files, but your tables can store compressed data.
That's how you can compress your table:

```
USE restoredDB;
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[YourBigTable] REBUILD PARTITION = ALL
WITH (DATA_COMPRESSION = PAGE)
```